# What is the best practice to overlay a Phonon.VideoWidget?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, overlay, phonon

The last couple of days I have tried to find a working solution to overlay a Phonon.VideoWidget with a simple QLabel. Sadly I wasn't able to find a working solution.

Here is what I have tried:

1. Parenting. I tried the "normal" parenting stuff addressing the QLabel to the VideoWidget. Result: The label does not show up at all.
2. QStackedLayout. As suggested here: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/31490-Overlaying-Widgets-on-top-of-VideoWidget. Result: Label is shown but always behind the video
3. GraphicsView. I tried a lot here as it looked like the most promising, but at the end the CPU load was just too high so the video did not play back. Setting the view's viewport to QGLWidget did not solve it. Result: Overlay works but video does not play caused by high CPU load.
4. Subclassing the VideoWidget. As mentioned here: https://wiki.qt.io/Overlay_widget_for_Phonon_VideoWidget. I took the same approach to create the overlay. This works just fine after all, except for the moveEvent. It does not look nice if the label is realigned after moving the widget has finished. Is there a way to update this already when moving VideoWidget?

I really hope someone can help me here (I use PySide but examples in C++ should work as well) or give me a pointer on where to look. Please let me know if I should share some code snippet to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is creating a new window that floats above your video widget. For example create a parentless QLabel and make sure that it moves in sync with your main window.

```
label = new QLabel();
label->setWindowFlags(Qt::ToolTip | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

In your QMainWindow subclass, override moveEvent and resizeEvent and do something like:

```
label->move(mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, height() - label->height())));
```

This keeps the label in the bottom-left corner, change it to fit your needs.